What is the strategy behind making GAMS licence non-free for academics?
I have not thoroughly look at many proprietary solvers during my optimisation journey yet. The ones I have used are Gurobi and CPLEX and I have several former comrade working at Hexaly and heard of Artelys a little.
Something in common I think with these four proprietary solvers is that they are all free for academics, they provide free licence for them and of course, are non-free for industrials. I believe among other reasons, that provide free advertisement among academics and their students.
However, I have just fallen onto Gams and, as of today, they seem to make their licence non-free, 700 dollars for academics. Of course, it is less than the industrial licence (3,500 dollars) for a permanent single user. I am curious about this choice and the reasons why they don't profit as much as possible from free advertisement among academics.

You could just as easily ask the companies behind other solvers why they don't make the license free for industry users. The answer is simple: because they ran the numbers and determined that "free advertising" wasn't worth it.

GAMS already has an academic license with the maximum number of variables or constraints ($\leq 5000$). Also, they provide functionality to make use of the NEOS server directly inside the GAMS without any limitation on the number of variables or constraints. However, some of its advanced functions may be limited as long as using the NEOS.
